# how to manage tile usercontrols(having listbox binding) in MVVM model?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

//this is usercontrol code

```
<ListBox  Name="OvernightAverageListBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OvernightAverageCollections}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Name="items" Background="{Binding BackColor}" Height="200" Width="200">
                <TextBlock  Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,10,0,0" Name="currentRate" Text="{Binding  Current_rate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" />
                <TextBlock Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,20,0,0" Name="rate_difference" Text="{Binding RateChange_Value}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" />
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,30,0,0" Name="productName" Text="{Binding Product_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

//this is binding code on view

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="Overnight Average" Tap="RateTile_Tap">
            <Grid x:Name="overnightAverage">
             <views:OvernightAverageTileControl x:Name="eventsView">       </views:OvernightAverageTileControl>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
</ListBox>
```

now acoording to my code the tiles are coming vertically means each tile is taking in one row.
but i want them to come both horizontally and vertically means two tiles in each row.
plz share ur suggetion i am new to xaml designing.

first image shows wat i am getting.

second image is wat i want.

thanks :)

[image: this is wat it is coming.]

[image: but i want like of this kind]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it successfully using WrapPanel in toolkit oct 2011.
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/upload/articles/WrapPanelDemo.zip

Comment: Grid would still be the better solution if you need to control the number of columns, as your question suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the StackPanel in your DataTemplate by a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Name="items" Background="{Binding BackColor}" Height="200" Width="200">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Current_rate}" ... />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding RateChange_Value}" ... />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Product_name}" ... />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

You may also specify absolute or relative widths of the columns and heights of the rows by setting the [ColumnDefinition.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and the [RowDefinition.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.height%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) properties.

Comment: Thanks for your great response.But i was not so clear wat i want so i am attaching some pics.Kindly see them & plz help me.

Comment: You can do that with a Grid, exactly as i wrote in my answer.